# X11 Error When Run as a Docker Container

Tags: x11, docker

I'm trying to run an application from a Docker container which is supposed to open a GUI widow (a video stream in my case). The Docker container is run on a Raspberry Pi and I SSH into the Pi from my Mac and then I issue the Docker run command. I have one problem here:

When I run the whole thing as follows, it works flawlessly:

I run the command as:

```
docker run -it --net=host --device=/dev/vcsm --device=/dev/vchiq -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix joesan/motion_detector bash
```

From the bash, that opens up after issuing the Docker run command, I install xauth

```
root@cctv:/raspi_motion_detection/project# apt-get install xauth
```

I then add the Xauth cookie using Xauth add and then I then run my Python program which shows the GUI window with the video stream!

So far so good. But, every time I don't want to be doing these steps all over again. So I wrote a small script to do this as below:

```
HOST=cctv

DISPLAY_NUMBER=$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d: -f2)
echo $DISPLAY_NUMBER

# Extract auth cookie
AUTH_COOKIE=$(xauth list | grep "^$(hostname)/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} " | awk '{print $3}')

# Add the xauth cookie to xauth
xauth add ${HOST}/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ${AUTH_COOKIE}

# Launch the container  
docker run -it --net=host --device=/dev/vcsm --device=/dev/vchiq -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix  joesan/motion_detector`
```

But this time it fails with the error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

I then tried to run the above script as a sudo user and I get the following:

```
xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
xauth: (argv):1:  bad "add" command line
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: The sequence seems mixed up between the two approaches. When you run the `docker -it ..` command, it launches the container, creates a bash shell inside the container, and places you there. I guess you execute the `apt-get install` and `xauth` commands inside the container. In the shell script, you seem to be running the xauth commands on the host, not inside the container.

Comment: How do I fix this? I mean how can I get the same effect of running xauth commands from inside the container? Should I do apt-get install xauth inside the container by writing it as a RUN command in my Docker file?

Comment: Is there any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apt-get install xauth` command should only be required once, and so you can include it in your Dockerfile so that it gets executed when you build your image.

```
RUN apt-get install xauth
```

For the `xauth add` command, you seem to be depending upon the DISPLAY variable, which is passed on to the container on startup. In this case, it would be better to create a shell script which does all of the initialization that you need at startup, and then launches your Python program. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=cctv
DISPLAY_NUMBER=$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d: -f2)
AUTH_COOKIE=$(xauth list | grep "^$(hostname)/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} " | awk '{print $3}')
xauth add ${HOST}/unix:${DISPLAY_NUMBER} MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ${AUTH_COOKIE}
python /path/to/program.py
```

Then, you can copy over this script during the build phase and set it as your command or entrypoint.

```
COPY init-script.bash /opt/program
CMD ["/bin/bash","/opt/program/init-script.bash"]
```

Comment: I almost ended up having a similar set up. I will test it and let you know if that worked!

Comment: Ok! So now I get this error: xauth:  unable to link authority file /root/.Xauthority, use /root/.Xauthority-n

Comment: @sparkr : Sorry, I'm not too familiar with `xauth` itself. It has a `-v` flag for verbose output, so maybe you can use that to get more information?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using this command on the host before running the container:

```
xhost +
```

After that, I was able to run my container with:

```
sudo docker run -it --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix test1
```

I didn't install `xauth` inside the container.

Comment: Note that turning off security is not something that should be done for machines which might be subject to attacks, i.e. anything connected to the Internet.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I looked for a more secure way to allow the docker container to access to the display and I found this :
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/xhost.htm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015536/xhost-command-for-docker-gui-apps-eclipse
So I replaced `xhost +` by `xhost +local:root` and it works (you can do `xhost -` if you previously allow access to everyone with `xhost +`)
Is it safe enough ?

Comment: Everything is a tradeoff. I would put the extra time in to have authorization enabled rather than not. If only you log into the machine then the restricted xhost plus is probably good enough.